# Understanding regex of non capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am little confused understanding the regex pattern below from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> ```
> (?:x)
> ```
>
> Matches 'x' but does not remember the match. The parentheses are called *non-capturing parentheses*, and let you define subexpressions for regular expression operators to work with. Consider the sample expression `/(?:foo){1,2}/`. If the expression was `/foo{1,2}/`, the `{1,2}` characters would apply only to the last 'o' in 'foo'. With the non-capturing parentheses, the `{1,2}` applies to the entire word 'foo'. For more information, see Using parentheses below.

I am not able to understand these two points:

1. Consider the sample expression `/(?:foo){1,2}/`. If the expression was `/foo{1,2}/`, the `{1,2}` characters would apply only to the last '`o`' in '`foo`'.
2. With the non-capturing parentheses, the `{1,2}` applies to the entire word '`foo`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as far as I know, the non capturing group has nothing to do with your immediate question, and both of the following patterns would match the same things:

```
/(?:foo){1,2}/
/(foo){1,2}/
```

The parentheses tell the regex engine that you want the quantity rule `{1,2}` to apply to the entire quantity.  Without the parentheses, the quantity defaults to applying to the immediately preceding character `o`:

```
/foo{1,2}/
```

This would match `foo` and `fooo`.

Comment: "mmediately preceding character o" is what I was looking for. Thanks